# RelativeLayout not adjusting to width of TextView properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

so my title pretty much explains it all. I have a calendar portion in my app, and the time of day wraps around into multiple lines like so

```
12
a
m
```

Now I want it to stay in one line like this 
`12 am`

and also for the RelativeLayout to correctly size the width of the column containing times. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is an image (please ignore the top, I am not done with the app yet)
[image]

Here is my XML

```
    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/calendar_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/days_header_divider"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/calendar_time_relativelayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/calendar_time_splitter_linearlayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:padding="0dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/hours_relativelayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time12am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time12am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time1am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time1am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time2am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time2am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time3am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time3am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time4am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time4am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time5am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time5am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time6am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time6am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time7am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time7am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time8am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time8am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time9am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="540dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time9am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time10am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time10am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time11am_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="660dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time11am"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time12pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="720dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time12pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time1pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="780dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time1pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time2pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="840dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time2pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time3pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="900dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time3pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time4pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="960dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time4pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time5pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1020dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time5pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time6pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1080dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time6pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time7pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1140dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time7pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time8pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1200dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time8pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time9pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1260dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time9pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time10pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1320dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/time10pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time11pm_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1380dp"
                            android:gravity="center|top"
                            android:text="@string/time11pm"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/sundayRelativeLayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2">

                        <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/mondayRelativeLayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2">

                        <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tuesdayRelativeLayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2">

                        <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/wednesdayRelativeLayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2">

                        <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/thursdayRelativeLayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2">

                        <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/fridayRelativeLayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2">

                        <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/saturdayRelativeLayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2">

                        <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/current_time_marker_linearlayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="0dp">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/current_time_line_view"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_weight="14"
                        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The outer container is a RelativeLayout with just the Header Columns in a LinearLayout.
Thanks!

Comment: Post your layout calendar_lines

Comment: It's just a background. It has no affect on the problem, I had the problem before including that layout. @FerdousAhamed

Comment: why you are not using a tablelayout??

Comment: I imagined this would be easier because if I used a TableLayout then I'd have to include a row for every 15 mins. So 15*4  = 1 hour, 4 * 24 = 96. So I'd need 96 rows, where as here I only need 7 relative layouts which I can fill anyway... @rafsanahmad007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the `RelativeLayout` with `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` while all other following layouts have `android:layout_weight="2"`. This means that every other column gets stretched twice as much as the first one.

Instead let the layout wrap its children. Like this you ensure that the times are not line-wrapped.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/hours_relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add attribute `android:weightSum="16.5"` to `calendar_time_splitter_linearlayout`.

**2.** Update `hours_relativelayout` to `android:layout_weight="2.5"`.

**3.** You should add `android:lines="1"` to all time `TextView`(`time12am_textview, time1am_textview....`) to make it `single` line.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/days_header_divider"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar_time_relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/calendar_time_splitter_linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:weightSum="16.5">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/hours_relativelayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2.5">

                <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time12am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time12am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time1am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time1am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time2am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time2am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time3am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time3am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time4am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time4am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time5am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time5am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time6am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time6am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time7am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time7am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time8am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time8am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time9am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="540dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time9am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time10am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time10am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time11am_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="660dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time11am"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time12pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="720dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time12pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time1pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="780dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time1pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time2pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="840dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time2pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time3pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="900dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time3pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time4pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="960dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time4pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time5pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1020dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time5pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time6pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1080dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time6pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time7pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1140dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time7pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time8pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1200dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time8pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time9pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1260dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time9pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time10pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1320dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time10pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time11pm_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1380dp"
                    android:gravity="center|top"
                    android:text="@string/time11pm"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lines="1" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sundayRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mondayRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tuesdayRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/wednesdayRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/thursdayRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fridayRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/saturdayRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <include layout="@layout/calendar_lines"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/current_time_marker_linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/current_time_line_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="14"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: I did not downvote, but I believe it is because you're only increasing the size of the column.